# VPN over Lancom router slows down MS office only

Tags: windows, vpn, fritzbox

I have the following problem: When connecting with Windows 10 to a Windows Server 2012 R2 via RDP and VPN (which is configured on a Lancom router), MS office (only!) is painfully slow. When using a Fritz!Box instead of the Lancom, everything works good. What can cause this? I am not a Windows user and don't know where to start.

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with the OSes so your expertise level in Windows is a moot point anyway. It has to do with the VPN itself.

Comment: The point is that it only affects MS Office and nothing else on the PC.